# OpenCV Stereo Reconstruction -- What is the difference between using the Q matrix and triangulation?

Tags: opencv, triangulation, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

Ive implemented a stereo pipeline in Matlab multiple times, and now I am trying to implement one in OpenCV. Ive been following Martin Peris's reconstruction: http://blog.martinperis.com/2012/01/3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-and-point.html

When implementing with Matlab, my pipeline goes like this: calibration -> rectification -> stereo matching -> unrectify/unwarp matches -> triangulate matches.

In OpenCV, the pipeline goes like this calibration -> rectification -> stereo matching -> reprojectTo3D

with the reprojectTo3D function here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20reprojectImageTo3D%28InputArray%20disparity,%20OutputArray%20_3dImage,%20InputArray%20Q,%20bool%20handleMissingValues,%20int%20ddepth%29

Is it not doing triangulation? How is this possible? Is it assuming the cameras are in a canonical setup and parallel already?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV pipeline gets a disparity map for triangulation from stereo matching, and the projection matrices of the cameras from calibration and rectification steps. You could use [triangualtePoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints) with positions of points viewed from both cameras and their projection matrices from [stereoRectify](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify) function. The main algorithm is the same, You just use slightly different intermediate products.

Comment: In my view, there is minor error in the answer. You could use triangualtePoints with positions of points viewed from both cameras and their projection matrices(not their positions) from stereoRectify function.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. I thought that projection matrices contain information about camera positions, but even if it's true, there is a lot more than that. Fixed.